# Click on disabled element using Actions class doesnt work

Tags: selenium, webdriver, action

I have a test where I need to click on a disabled button.
I am using the Actions class to do this. 
When the user clicks on the button, an alert is generated. 
Below is the code i have written:

```
Actions mouseActions = new Actions(driver);
mouseActions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("disabled_element_id"))).click().build().perform();
```

Then I try to switch to the alert I get exception:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: No alert is present.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Selenium will not click a disabled element.  I would suggest an approach where you use JavaScriptExecutor to click the button via javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `JavaScriptExecutor` for this task, `WebDriver` is not able to click on elements which are disabled or invisible. So try something like

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
js.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"button[id=yourButton]\").click()");
```

Answer (score 2):

Selenium has been written to replicate user interaction, therefore will not allow interaction with disabled objects as a human would not be able to either.

you can either;

- Replicate the process a user would do to enable a button.
- Use JavaScript to enable or perform the interaction

Comment: Selenium is often used to write tests of web-app. And good QA engineer also tests that button is not just disabled but also does not do any unexpected action when it is clicked

Comment: Clicking a button that has been marked as disabled by HTML is retesting the functionality of HTML rendering in the browser, not the functionality of your web-app.

Perhaps a better test would be to assert the button is disabled by inspecting the HTML?  If you really wanted to send a click to a disabled button (which I suggest would not be the normal use case 99% of the time), then you can use Actions to move the mouse to the button and fire a click