# Selenium throws NoSuchElementException when trying to find an option, even though the option exists

Tags: c#, jquery, selenium, nosuchelementexception

One of the scripts that previously was working is currently failing and I am not able to debug it.

Selenium throws `NoSuchElementException` on the following line:

```
SelectPrimeraCompetencia.SelectByText(valorCompetencia, true);
```

Value of `valorCompetencia` is `APR`, so the line becomes:

```
SelectPrimeraCompetencia.SelectByText(APR, true);
```

`SelectPrimeraCompetencia` represents a `SelectElement` with the following code:

```html
<select class="w100x100" data-notrack="true" data-bind="
         options: $root.sistemasCalificacionValor
        ,optionsText:'clave'
        ,value: sistemaCalificacionValorSeleccionado
        ,optionsCaption: ''
        ,enable: !$root.soloLectura()
        ,css: { 'disabled' : $root.soloLectura }
      ">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="">SUS</option>
  <option value="">APR</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, the third option's text is `APR`

If I check `SelectPrimeraCompetencia` at runtime, we can see the following options:

[image: SelectElement at runtime]

Which confirms that option at index 2 text is `APR`

However exception still appears:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I see inline attributes for 'enabled' and 'disabled'. I'm not familiar with the code so my best guess is that webdriver thinks the element cannot be interacted with. You could try to select the element in a different way to prove or disprove my guess.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18662992/2092742

> You need to use `JavaScriptExecutor` for this task, `WebDriver` is not able to click on elements which are disabled or invisible. So try something like
>
> ```
> JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
> js.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"button[id=yourButton]\").click()");
> ```

Answer (score 0):

How about looping through the oprions of the select element and select the option by index.

This could look like this:

```
foreach(var item in SelectPrimeraCompetencia.Options)
{
    int count = 0;
    if(item.Text == valorCompetencia)
    {
        SelectPrimeraCompetencia.SelectByIndex(count);
    }
    else
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```